# How can i create menu like in the example?

Tags: customization, menus, sub-menu

i try to create menu loop with structure like below, but i cant, default function wp_nav_menu doesn't allow to do that, i don't understand hot to do it. I need structure like in example with data-remodal-target count and data-remodaul-id.
How can i do it?

```
            <nav class="main-menu">
              <ul class="row between">
                <li class="main-menu__item">
                  <a class="main-menu__link" href="#" data-remodal-target="modal00">News</a>
                  <div class="modal main-menu__modal-wrapper" data-remodal-id="modal00">
                    <button class="button_close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
                    <div class="modal-wrapper">
                      <div class="modal__content">
                        <ul class="main-menu__sub-menu animated fadeIn">
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page1.html">page 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page2.html">page 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu__item">
                  <a class="main-menu__link" href="#" data-remodal-target="modal01">Media</a>
                  <div class="modal main-menu__modal-wrapper" data-remodal-id="modal01">
                    <button class="button_close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
                    <div class="modal-wrapper">
                      <div class="modal__content">
                        <ul class="main-menu__sub-menu animated fadeIn">
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page1.html">page 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page2.html">page 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu__item">
                  <a class="main-menu__link" href="#" data-remodal-target="modal02">Serv</a>
                  <div class="modal main-menu__modal-wrapper" data-remodal-id="modal02">
                    <button class="button_close" data-remodal-action="close"></button>
                    <div class="modal-wrapper">
                      <div class="modal__content">
                        <ul class="main-menu__sub-menu animated fadeIn">
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page1.html">page 1</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="main-menu__sub-menu__item">
                            <a class="main-menu__sub-menu__link" href="page2.html">page 2</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: You'll need to write a walker function

Comment: @cjbj Thx, but i don't know what's walker function.

Comment: google is your friend: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class with your own class to modify `WP Nan Menus`.

One of the best example is [wp_bootstrap_navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php). You can also extend walker class to built custom navigation structures.